# How to identify the distribution being sampled by this algorithm?

Tags: distributions, monte-carlo, accept-reject

I've been studying a piece of code lately that uses the Monte Carlo acceptance-rejection method to draw random samples from a distribution I'm struggling to identify. Here's a Python implementation:

```py
import numpy as np

def gen_alpha(sigma_alpha=0.000125):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    f_max = 4.0 * sigma_alpha
    while True:
        alpha = rng.normal(0.0, sigma_alpha)
        if rng.uniform(low=0, high=f_max) < np.sin(alpha) and alpha < np.pi / 2:
            return alpha
```

This code comes from a model for computing reflections off a surface with surface roughness. We use this function to generate a new surface normal vector that forms an angle alpha (sampled from `gen_alpha()`) with the actual surface normal. I just have no idea what this distribution actually is. For the record, I've included a histogram of 10,000 samples from this distribution.

[image: A histogram of 10,000 samples from the gen_alpha function.]

In the full code, we use this alpha along with a uniform random $\phi$ to create a Cartesian three-vector:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
alpha = gen_alpha()
phi = rng.uniform(low=0, high=2 * np.pi)
vec = np.array([
    np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(phi),
    np.sin(alpha) * np.sin(phi),
    np.cos(alpha)
])
```

The x- and y-components that result seem to follow Normal distributions with width equal to sigma_alpha. This might be relevant to help identify the distribution, I don't know.

Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: What do you know about acceptance-rejection sampling? If you read this intro on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling you should identify the targeted density.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Following some of the information there, I believe the density of the distribution is g(x; 0, sigma_alpha) sin(x), but part of the problem with this is the impact of the `alpha < pi / 2` line in the code. That does seem to effect the distribution's shape when sigma_alpha is increased, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it

Comment: The indicator function that $\alpha<\pi/2$ is part of the target density. To me this is a strange constraint as negative values of $\alpha$ are not excluded...